# Laravel Ajax Route can not be found

Tags: ajax, laravel, datatables

I am having issues with an Ajax get request within Laravel 10

The following is my route

```
Route::get('members', [MemberController::class, 'getmembers'])->name('member.getmembers');
```

Which should be pointing to the following on my MemberController

```
public function getMembers(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->ajax()) {
        $data = Member::where('active', '=', 'Y')->get();
        return Datatables::of($data)
                ->addIndexColumn()
                ->addColumn('action', function($row){
                    $btn = '<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="edit btn btn-primary btn-sm">View</a>';
                    return $btn;
                })
                ->rawColumns(['action'])
                ->make(true);
    }

}
```

Which is called into my Blade View

```
@php
        $config = [
            'processing' => true,
            'serverSide' => true,
            'ajax' => "{{ route('members.getmembers') }}",

        ];
    @endphp

    <x-adminlte-datatable id="members" :heads=$heads head-theme="dark" striped hoverable with-button beautify :config=$config>

    </x-adminlte-datatable>
```

I am given the following error in the console -> Network -> Response

```
"message": "The route %7B%7B%20route('member.getmembers')%20%7D%7D could not be found.",
"exception": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\NotFoundHttpException",
"file": "F:\\XAMPP\\htdocs\\edparkadmin\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\AbstractRouteCollection.php",
"line": 44,
```

Answer (score 1):

While you are in a @php scope,

```
'ajax' => "{{ route('members.getmembers') }}",
```

should be like this:

```
'ajax' => route('members.getmembers'),
```

---

Hint: When you see something like %7B%7B, you can put the message into an url decoder but this specific substring must let you know that you misused this interpolation syntax.